# Matlab does not call Python class inherited method

Tags: python, matlab, inheritance, python-can

I am using Matlab to call Python CAN functions from the python-can package.

The code in Python works fine, but when called from Matlab it does not. The issue seems to be that Matlab is calling the send() method from the parent class instead of the child class. Matlab needs to call the send() method from the child class.

This link shows the Matlab limitations to Python support:
https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/limitations-to-python-support.html

Here is my python code:

```
import can

bus = can.interface.Bus(bustype = "slcan", channel = 'COM6', bitrate = 250000)
print(type(bus))
dataToSend = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
CAN_Msg = can.Message(arbitration_id = 0x1, is_extended_id = True, data = dataToSend)
bus.send(CAN_Msg)
```

Output:

```
<class 'can.interfaces.slcan.slcanBus'>
```

Here is my code in Matlab:

```
kwa = pyargs('bustype', 'slcan', 'channel', 'COM6', 'bitrate', 250000);
bus = py.can.interface.Bus(kwa);
class(bus)

dataToSend = py.list({int32(1), int32(2), int32(3), int32(4), int32(5), int32(6), int32(7), int32(8)});
kwa = pyargs('arbitration_id', hex2dec('1'), 'is_extended_id', 'True', 'data', dataToSend);

CAN_Msg = py.can.Message(kwa);

bus.send(CAN_Msg);
```

Output:

```
ans =

    'py.can.interface.Bus'

Error using bus>send (line 171)
Python Error: NotImplementedError: Trying to write to a readonly bus?
```

Is there an easy way to use the python send() method in Matlab? Any ideas to call the python code are welcome, even if I have to create a new python library or modify the python library code.